# Check whether user is logged in or not in public files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I on my projects i have routes like

```
resources :main, path: '/' do
    collection do
      get 'about'
      get 'blog'
      get 'resources'
      get 'contact'
      get 'projects-and-tutorials'
    end
  end
```

and public files for them like contact.html and about.html

Is it possible to have haml files for public routes ?

also how can check if user is logged in or not in public files

( i think it can be done with haml but not in html files but right now i am having html public files)

System is using Devise gem for authentication

Comment: You are having main_controller..right?

Comment: yes I surely have that, but dont have methods for it

Comment: You can not check for a logic in an HTML file, you must have them as .haml or .erb.

Comment: but when i change them to haml or erb it shows "No route matches [GET] "/projects-and-tutorials"

Comment: public folder can only contain the files that can be rendered to browser directly without any processing on server.

Answer (score 1):

just add following line to main_controller.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

and check in view file is user logged in or not

Comment: but how can i check if user is logged in or not in html files as i mentioned i have html files in public folder and routes mentioned are showing outputs from these html files

Comment: you are having contact.html.erb in main folder..right?

Comment: yes i just created it main folder, will try for user conditions in these files

Comment: so there you can check if user_signed_in? it will return true if user is signed in else false

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your route, the final url would be

- /main/about
- /main/blog

and so on.

You need to specific methods for those views in the main controller. And in the main controller, you need to do the user validation.